# ports not forwarding - my ISP tells me they are not blocking — router is Sagemcom F@st 526

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, isp

I am trying to run both Golem and Monero on my Linux Ubuntu 16.4 LTS. I am using a Sagemcom F@ST 5260 router with Charter Communications as my ISP.

I am required to forward ports 3282,40102, and 40103 for Golem and port 18081 for Monero. I also forward port 22 for ssh.

Aside from port 22, none of the other ports are being forwarding. Not only do the programs fail to connect, but sites like [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org) fail on all the above mentioned ports except 22.

I have worked with Charter trying to resolve this issue. They tell me they do not block ports. My router setting are good when they inspected them.

These ports used to work. I did trial runs in December, January, and Feburary when I could connect Golems testnet.

I'm not sure where the problem may be:

- The ISP, who claim they are not blocking (per 2nd level support)?
- The router (I already exchanged it)?
- The applications (but it's not just one application failing)?
- Something in Ubuntu (maybe the iptables)?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all of those ports for TCP?

Comment: @grawity, TCP-UDP